# Prerender.io: Returning 404 instead of 200

Tags: prerender

When I access a page in the browser I get a proper 200 from the server:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/May/2019:19:53:50 +0200] "GET /retourneren HTTP/1.1" 200 2889 "https://mysite.nl/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
```

However when I add the url in prerender I get a 400:

```
3.90.111.223 - - [02/May/2019:19:50:39 +0200] "GET /retourneren HTTP/1.1" 404 10050 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/61.0.3163.59 Safari/537.36 Prerender (+https://github.com/prerender/prerender)" "-"
```

therefor the page is not getting cached. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like you might be setting the prerender-status-code meta tag on the page and setting it to "404", which would make Prerender.io return a 404 response code directly.

Can you confirm whether or not that meta tag is being set in the HTML of the page?